# JSP - Testing document.body.offsetWidth

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I need to test the browser window width in JSP, to determine whether or not I have to set a value in the request object. Typically I would achieve this with something like this:

```
if(document.body.offsetWidth < xxxx){
  // ...
}
```

But I don't know how to do it with a JSP expression.

Comment: You understand that you can't directly mix JavaScript with Java, right? Why do you need this?

Answer (score 0):

You might misunderstand that `jsp` and `javascript` existed on same file. Yes but `JSP` part compiles on server side itself comes to `client`.

**You can't do that with `JSP`.**

JSP compiles on `serverside` Where as `javascript` plays on browser i.e on client side.

[Do it with javascript](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/static2.shtml).You should do it in `document load`

Answer (score 0):

when you do `if(document.body.offsetWidth < xxxx)` you are doing it at client side. Now if you want to propagate some client side value to server side i.e to some java class(most of the cases it will be servlets) then you have two options:-

```
1)Make an AJAX call. (You can also use jquery here to make AJAX call).
```

Here is the small example, you can find ample on google

```
$.ajax({ 
type: 'GET', 
dataType: 'json', 
data: { windowWidth: "100"}
url: servlerURL, 
success: function(reply) { 

},
error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { 

}
```

});

```
or

2)Submit the form
```